# Случайный выбор из таблицы и внесение его в другую таблицу

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица в базе:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab2 ( 
    username varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    den date NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY username (username)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Код

```
mysql_query(
  "INSERT INTO tab2 (username, den) VALUES ((SELECT username FROM tab1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1), current_date)",
  $con
);
```

делает случайный выбор `username` из таблицы `tab1` и добавляет результат в `tab2` в такое же поле `username` и добавляет текущую дату в поле `den`.

Так вот, 1 запись пишется в `tab2` только один раз, если дать команд второй раз, то она не пишется по новой в новую строку, хотя по идее должна добавляться неограниченное количество раз.

Comment: раз не пишется, значит ругается. как? а то сейчас можно только гадать

Comment: Ошибок не выдает. В базе 10 записей. Запускаю код 1 раз. Случайно  Пользователь1 пишется в эту таблицу с датой занесения записи. Запускаю еще раз случайно Пользователь2 также заносится как и первый. Запускаю еще раз и если случайно снова выпадает Пользователь 1 то запись не вноситься. Если в таблице все 10 пользователей то следующая 11 запись со случайным пользователем не появляется.

Comment: значит, скорее всего, у вас поле с пользователем не может иметь повторов. смотрите структуру базы

Comment: Ну и в вопрос структуру БД не помешало бы добавить ;)

Comment: -- Структура таблицы `tab2`


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tab2` (
  `username` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `den` date NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: @Григорий, ru.SO это сервис в формате вопрос-ответ. Поэтому  добавлять решение проблемы в **сам вопрос** не правильно. Я вынес ваше решение в отдельный ответ, возможно он поможет кому-то еще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы определяете поле `username`, как уникальное. Поэтому, при выполнении запроса на добавление пользователя с уже существующим именем ничего не происходит.

Чтобы записи начали добавляться, вам достаточно убрать ограничение на уникальность. Запрос на создание таблицы будет иметь вид:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab2 ( 
    username varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    den date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```